# ¿Por qué es "lo vi" pero "le dije"?

Tags: complemento-directo

No entiendo por qué:
¿Viste a Juan?
Sí, **lo** vi.

¿Le dijiste a Juan?
Sí, **le** dije.

Creo que Juan es el receptor del verbo en ambas oraciones, entonces no entiendo por qué en una se utiliza "lo" de complemento directo, y en la otra "le" de complemento indirecto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Viste a Juan? Sí, lo vi.

¿Qué viste? Vi a **Juan**. Juan es Objeto Directo = lo.

> ¿Le dijiste a Juan? Sí, le dije.

¿Qué dijiste? Dije **algo** (a Juan). No "Dije a Juan". Juan es Objeto Indirecto = le.

Answer (score 0):

Trataré de explicar el porqué de cada oración.

- ¿Viste a Juan? Sí, lo vi. Aquí estamos viendo a Juan como el objeto directo. Entonces decimos "lo" porque estamos sustituyendo el nombre de Juan por un pronombre que si fuera femenino sería "la". En España prefieren decir "le" para ambos géneros y aunque los académicos lo consideren incorrecto es la norma y se entiende perfectamente.
- ¿Le dijiste a Juan? Sí, le dije. Aquí hay un objeto indirecto. ¿Qué le dijiste a Juan? Juan es el receptor del verbo y al haber un objeto indirecto tenemos que poner "le" para indicar que hay algo que afecta al objeto directo. Al decir**le** algo a Juan, en él recae la acción del verbo.

Para objeto indirecto es Lo/La y para el indirecto Le/Se dependiendo del caso.

Comment: Actually, *le* for masculine single direct object is perfectly accepted by the RAE. They acknowledge the common use of *les* in the plural but don't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

La segunda conversación no está bien formada. El verbo *decir* es transitivo y requiere objeto directo, que aquí no aparece. Tal como la copias, es un vulgarismo que puede querer decir dos cosas:

1. ¿Se lo dijiste a Juan? Sí, se lo dije.
2. ¿Avisaste a Juan? Sí, le avisé (o *Sí, lo avisé*).

El problema puede estar en construcciones como la segunda; aquí, el pronombre *le* funciona como objeto directo. En general, para un objeto directo masculino se usa *lo*, pero en algunos lugares (principalmente España) también se usa *le* cuando se refiere a una persona. Es un caso de leísmo aceptado por la RAE, aunque no recomendado.

De todos modos, en la segunda conversación que nos muestras no es eso lo que ocurre. Simplemente, falta el objeto directo (y no debería ser así), por eso se te hace rara. Si lo añadimos, seguro que la ves natural:

> ¿Le dijiste a Juan que viniera? Sí, se lo dije.

Comment: Me gustaría que quien ha puesto el -1 me explique por qué.